# WPF, How do I force a textbox to update

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I'm playing around with WPF. I am limited to the .Net framework 3.5.  I want to update a text box with simple status text while I run some long method.  No matter what I try, I cannot seem to get the text box to update until the long method has completed.  I have tried threading / using the controls dispatcher etc.  In the example below, I have reverted back to simply hiving off the long method to a thread but it still wont work.  The TextStatus textbox never gets updated until after the long method (LoadDevices) has completed.  Can someone tell me how to do this?  Any help much appreciated.

```
    private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateStatus("Searching for devices, please wait . . .");
        var t = new Thread(LoadDevices);
        t.Start();            
    }

    private void UpdateStatus(string status)
    {
        TextStatus.AppendText(status);
        TextStatus.InvalidateVisual();
    }
```

Comment: Is `TextStatus` bound to your textbox? Is it a DependencyProperty?

Comment: That *seems* like it should work, though it would be better to utilize a binding.

Comment: Just a note, when you work with WPF, it's kinda better to use MVVM pattern. Makes many things easier etc.

Comment: Are you sure your bottleneck is where you think it is?  Have you verified that `LoadDevices` really takes that long to execute?  If you are performing a large UI update upon completion, like binding a data grid, perhaps that is where the delay is coming from.

Comment: I'm calling update status before calling loaddevices.  I just want to force the textbox to update.  No matter what I try, it wont update until all code has run.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not providing enough code to figure out the problem. Still, fact is that your UI is blocked.

Try the following, maybe it helps you figure it out (not using `Task` since it's not available in `.NET Framework 3.5`). It tries to simulate your long running `LoadDevices()` method while keeping the UI responsive.

**MainWindows.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="120"
        Width="400">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Click="UpdateButtonClick" Grid.Row="0">Update</Button>
        <TextBox Name="TextStatus" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindows.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UpdateButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateStatus("Searching for devices, please wait");
            var thread = new Thread(LoadDevices);
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void LoadDevices()
        {
            // Your long running "load devices" implementation goes here
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => UpdateStatus(".")));
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => UpdateStatus(" done")));
        }

        private void UpdateStatus(string status)
        {
            TextStatus.AppendText(status);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But yeah, you should prefer MVVM, Data binding, Commands, etc. and try to avoid stuffing logic into codebehind.

Comment: There is no data binding here. I just want to update a textbox with status strings. I do not want to  do this from withing LoadDevices as there will be other methods besides it where I also want to update the status.  So I envisage a method that calls various long methods, before each call, I update status.

Comment: @user2026382 But it *should* be data-bound regardless of updating from `LoadDevices`. I would take this advice.

Comment: There is no databinding but updating Text property is a basic scenario for binding `<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />`. That would take care of updates w/o explicitly appending text.

Comment: There is no property to bind the text box to. Where are you getting "MyProperty" from ?

Comment: You define the property in your ViewModel part of the MVVM pattern implementation, but maybe we should skip that for now.

Comment: There is no view model.  The question is as simple as it states. Just a xaml window. Code behind runs some methods and wants to update a textbox.  Its as simple as that.

Comment: @user2026382 HIs current code doesn't even use MVVM, he's just saying you *should* use MVVM. He's also saying the same thing the question comments are; your code should work (this post proves it, just ignore the updates from "LoadDevices"), so you are missing something. Perhaps remove the "InvalidateVisual" that isn't necessary?

Comment: I've tried removing InvalidateVisual, it doesn't work and like I say, I do not want to be calling updatestatus from LoadDevices or any other long method. The textbox simply will not update until all code is complete, no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Task library.  You will need to download this for .NET 3.5 : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24940

```
Task task = new Task(new Action(LoadDevices));
task.Start();
```

There are several ways to do this:
http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/

Comment: Yes but there is a download that makes most of the basics Task available in 3.5.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried delegates, that may be what you are looking for although it seems you may of tried this already. Inside your LoadDevices thread method, you could delegate back to invoke UpdateStatus with whatever text you want while your long method is running.

The other case I see with the wording of your question is something local to the method Update-status is trying to change the text by a call to it. However, it cannot for some reason.

This may be compleatly irrelevant to WPF, but in Forms:

I'm assuming you have your loading thread somewhere else. I don't see you calling a doWork() or equivalent method in the thread though. If you want to update the status as your loading thread loads devices you could do:

```
    private delegate void UpdateStatusDel(string text); //This at your declarations
    UpdateStatusHandler = new UpdateStatusDel(UpdateStatus); //To initialize the delegate to /       //point to your update textbox function
    //say you have  
    string updateText = "Loading 10% done";
    //Then, in your thread you could invoke
    [locationOfHandeler].Invoke(UpdateStatusHandler, new object[] { updateText });
```